# How to get asp.net listbox size with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I need to check that my asp.net listbox is not empty when I submit the form. I want to do it with jQuery.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var length = $('#ListBox1 option').size();        
        // or var length = $('#ListBox1').children().size();     

        if (length > 0) {
        // submit form
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the client ID of the listbox first

```
<%= myListbox.ClientID %>
```

then you can use the object as a regular listbox in Javascript by accessing all the regular members.

```
var items = $("#<%= myListbox.ClientID %> option").length;
```

Its not using jQuery but you could also use the built in asp.net validator to do this

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ListBox1" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"/>
```

Comment: Your right Aristos :) I have it on my notepad but for some reason it didn't make it over on the retype heh. Added and edited

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the following condition:

$("#YourListBoxId option").length > 0

Answer (score 1):

try to integrate this check `$("#yourListBoxId option").size()>0` into onClick event on sumbit button. If it return true - your listbox have values.